# Show that an inverse mapping $ g = f^{-1}: J \to I $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

**Question:**

Let $f: I \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous, injective funtion. Show that its inverse mapping $ g = f^{-1}: J  \to I $ is continuous, where, $I = (x,y)$ and $J = f(I)$.

I understand this intuitively but can't come up with a proof.

Comment: Question unclear.  $(x,y)$ in the real numbers?  An interval where the function is defined?  If so, continuity implies strictly monotonic.

Comment: Note that $f^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if $f$ maps open sets to open sets.

Comment: What can you say about the image $f[(x', y')]$ of an open interval $(x', y') \subseteq (x, y)$ under $f$?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $J = f((x,y))$ and $g: = f^{-1} : J \to I =(x,y)$ from the continuous  bijection $f : I \to J$. We have that $g$ is increasing (show). Now let  $a \in I $ be an arbitrary point and $b = f(a)$.

Given any $\epsilon > 0$ as $I$ is open we may say that $(a-\epsilon, a + \epsilon)$. Thus, $f(a - \epsilon) = b - \alpha$ and $f(a + \epsilon) = b + \beta$, where $\alpha >0$ and $\beta > 0$.

Let $\delta = \min \{\alpha, \beta\}$. As $g$ is increasing, $z \in J$,

$$\begin{align}b - \delta < z < b + \delta &\Rightarrow b - \alpha < z < b + \beta\\&\Rightarrow g(b - \alpha) <  g(z) < g(b + \beta)\\ &\Rightarrow a - \epsilon < g(z) < \alpha + \epsilon\end{align}$$

You may conclude that $g$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: Must $ f $ be a bijection or just injective?

Comment: Think, a injective function mapping its domain to the image is what?

Comment: Oh wow, I did not even catch that. That clears a lot up:P

Comment: That's great!..

Comment: There's a part I'm confused about; what does it mean when you say that because $ I $ is open we may say that $ (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon) $ ?

Comment: Definition of open set. You may also see as a point in the interior of $I$. But as $I$ is open then $I = int I$.

Comment: ok I see. ill think about this some more. thank you so much for the help

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help!